# Sketch the set $A\cap B$ in the Argand plane, where $A=\{z:|\frac{z+1}{z-1}|\leq 1\}$ and $B=\{z:|z|-\operatorname{Re}z\leq 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, problem-solving

Sketch the set $A\cap B$  in the Argand plane,  where $A=\{z:|\frac{z+1}{z-1}|\leq 1\}$ and $B=\{z:|z|-\operatorname{Re}z\leq 1\}$

In this problem, I can only make out $A=\{z:|\frac{z+1}{z-1}|\leq 1\}=\{z:|z+1|\leq |z-1|\}$ . So, if, we consider $z=a+ib$ , then, $z\in \mathbb {C}$ if $(a+1)^2+b^2\leq (a-1)^2+b^2$ which means, $(a+1)^2\leq (a-1)^2$ and hence, $a\leq 0$. Also, if $|z|-\operatorname{Re}z\leq 1$, then, $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a\leq 1$ which essentially means,  $a^2+b^2\leq (1+a)^2$ due to which , $b^2\leq 2a+1$ .  But I dont have a clue how how to proceed further.  I am not quite getting this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: You are essentially finished, to the point where I don't understand why you're not _actually_ finishing.  Do you understand what the Argand plane is and what the notation $A \cap B$ means?  If so, are you having an issue graphing either of $a \leq 0$ or $b^2 \leq 2a +1$ to find their intersection?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes! exactly...

Comment: I had a couple questions there, so I'm still not sure what you need help on.  I'll just try one question: Are you saying you don't know how to graph $a \leq 0$ on the Argand plane?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes! That and the fact how to graph $b^2\leq 2a+1$ in an analytical way in an Argand plane...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I will be replacing $a$ with $x$ and $b$ with $y$ in the following in order to match the graphs on WolframAlpha.  This only changes labels, as the Argand plane is the $(a,b)$-plane and we will be graphing on the $(x,y)$-plane.*

We are left with the question of how to graph the set of points in the $(x,y)$-plane such that $x \leq 0$ and $y^2 \leq 2x+1$.

The most common method is to note that all the expressions involved ($x$, $0$, $y^2$, $2x+1$) are continuous functions of $x,y$, and so we will first graph the inequalities $x=0$ and $y^2 = 2x+1$ and then check the regions these graphs split the plane into.

For instance, the graph of [$x=0$ is a vertical line on the $y$-axis](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x+%3D+0) and then checking the region to the left and to the right of this vertical line shows that [the region to the left and the vertical line itself is $A$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x+%3C%3D+0+and+y%5E2+%3E%3D+0+with+axes).

Similarly, the graph of $y^2 = 2x+1$ can be recognized as equivalent to $x = \frac12y^2 - \frac12$, which is [a parabola open to the right with vertex as $(-1/2, 0)$ and $y$-intercepts as $(0, \pm 1)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+y%5E2+%3D+2x%2B1).  Then once again testing the regions, we find [$B$ is this parabola along with the region to its right](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+y%5E2+%3C%3D+2x%2B1+with+axes)

Finally, this means that the intersection $A \cap B$ is the [region between $x=0$ and $y^2 = 2x+1$ along with its boundary](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+x+%3C%3D+0+and+y%5E2+%3C%3D+2x%2B1+with+axes).

Comment: Thank you! I just got a little confused ...Thanks a lot!...

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the fact that, in the original definition of $A$, the numbers $z \in \mathbb{C} $ for which $z-1 = 0$ are to be excluded, so you have to keep track of this when manipulating the expressions:

$$
A = \{ x : |\frac{z+1}{z-1}| \leq 1 \} = \{ x : |z+1| \leq |z-1| \wedge z \neq 1 \} .
$$

Now, having that in the end $z=a+ib \in A \ \ \text{iff} \ \ a < 0$ the additional condition $z \neq 1$ is useless, but in other circumstances this could not be the case. 
Apart from that, the request is to sketch the set resulting from the intersection of $A$ and $B$ on the complex plane, so you can proceed on the Argand plane $(a, b)$ like you would in the ordinary $(x,y)$ coordinate plane, once you have the analytic expression of the two sets in terms of $a$ and $b$. So, actually, you have done almost all the preliminary work in obtaining the pair of conditions:

$$
\cases{
a \leq 0 & (from the definition of $A$) \\
b^2 < 2a + 1 \Rightarrow a > \frac{1}{2} \left( b^2 - 1 \right) & (from the definition of $B$)}
$$

So you have now to proceed to:

- sketch $A$ (a half-plane)
- sketch $B$ (a curve)
- outlining the intersection of the two sets

In doing this, if you are familiar with the ordinary cartesian plane, consider that in the Argand plane the $a$- and $b$-axis are omologous to the $x$- and $y$-axis in the cartesian plane.